# Switch locale in URL with different arguments on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, multilingual

I have 3 links to switch locale in Symfony2.

```
 <a href="{{ path( app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'pl'}) }}"><img alt="Polski" class="flags" src="{{ asset('bundles/gogscms/images/pol.png') }}"></a>
 <a href="{{ path( app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'en'}) }}"><img alt="English" class="flags" src="{{ asset('bundles/gogscms/images/eng.png') }}"></a>
 <a href="{{ path( app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'it'}) }}"><img alt="Italiano" class="flags" src="{{ asset('bundles/gogscms/images/ita.png') }}"></a>
```

Everything is good, when I don't have any additional argument in Controlers. E.g ( pattern:  /{_locale} )

```
public function indexAction(){

...

    }
```

Unfortunally, when I have some additional argument (e.g:  pattern:  `/page/{id}/{name}/{_locale}` ) I get error in these links

> route has some missing mandatory parameters

Anyone has got any idea how should look like correct link? This should work always - when there is no arguments and when is `n` or `n + 1` arguments.

Or maybe there is another way to change the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the `app.request.attributes`.

If you don't know them :

```
{{path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge ({'_locale':'pl' }))  }}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how many arguments i have. These links are in layout.html.twig and They must be generated automatically. E.g First pattern is:  /{_locale} , secound : /page/{id}/{name}/{_locale} and next is /news/{id}/{_locale}

Comment: `Method "parameters" for object "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag" does not exist`  I use Symfony2.1 - maybe that's why?

Comment: Thanks for help, but should be `app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')`. Now everything is good :)